What type of top hinge pin for a heavy 6ft field gate with a rising rocker plate?
I'm looking to hang a 6ft hardwood field gate between 7" posts and need to use a rocker plate as a rising hinge for the bottom hinge due to the gradient of the path.
What's the best type of hinge pin for the top hinge? The common options seem to be hook-on-plate, lock-through-hook, and hook-to-bolt.
Thanks for any advice.

Got pics of the gate and posts?
